# Can I change the package name in appxmanifest for a UWP app?

Tags: visual-studio, appxmanifest

Perhaps it's a silly question but can I change the package name in the appxmanifest to be something intelligible instead of "c13sd-545sd4..."? I did not published my app yet.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to change publisher display name and package name

Publisher display name steps:
    package.appxmanifest-> Packaging -> Publisher Display Name

Package Name steps:
    package.appxmanifest-> Packaging -> Package Name

But its not possible to change Publisher name.

Answer (score 0):

Go to UWP,Click to Package.appxmanifest=>Go to Package Name=>Edit Name.